# What is the etymology of $PS1?

Tags: bash, shell, zsh, history, bourne-shell

What do the letters `PS` stand for in `$PS1`?

Is it actually "Prompt String"?

Where did `$PS1` first appear?

Comment: Version 8 Unix says "prompt string": https://superuser.com/a/57613/334516

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The V7 `sh.1` man page](https://github.com/dspinellis/unix-history-repo/blob/Research-V7-Snapshot-Development/usr/man/man1/sh.1) defines `PS1` as

> Primary prompt string, by default ‘$ ’.

So yes, letters P and S in `PS1` stand for “prompt string”.

`PS1` was introduced with the Bourne shell in V7; older shells didn’t have anything like this. The Thompson shell, used before V7, [didn’t have variables at all](https://github.com/dspinellis/unix-history-repo/blob/Research-V6-Snapshot-Development/usr/doc/man/man1/sh.1). [The PWB (Mashey) shell introduced single-character alphabetic variables](https://grosskurth.ca/bib/1976/mashey-command.pdf) (`$a` through `$z`), with special meaning given to `$n` (the number of arguments given to the shell), `$p` (the search path), `$r` (the last command’s return code), `$s` (the user’s login directory), and `$t` (the terminal identification); `$$` was also understood, and replaced by the shell’s process number. These were refined into the more general concept of environment variables during [the design of V7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PWB_shell#Descendants).

Comment: now the only question I have is why is the login directory `$s`...

Comment: This superuser post can probably do with a better answer by you, since the accepted answer  says V7 didn't have manpages and V8 introduced them: https://superuser.com/a/57613/334516

Comment: Good point @muru; since it’s a community wiki I edited the existing answer.